# JQuery Ajax and concatenated string

Tags: jquery, ajax, concatenation

I`m trying to do an Ajax Request but for some reason it wont accept my concatenated string.
When the query should have some parameters it leaves them out and makes GET call.

Here is a tiny piece of the code that I`ve written.

```
        var queryString = "";
        var separator = "?";

        for (param in config.query) {
            queryString = queryString.concat(separator, param, "=", config.query[param]);
            separator = "&";
        }

        var url = config.url + queryString;

        $.ajax({
            url : url,
```

Comment: config.query is just another object literal which contains parameters like confiq.query.module, config.query.page, config.query.action etc. config is a local variable and I extend it with a another object literal which comes as parameter. I wonder if that might be the case. But it is just weird because it actually constructs the string as it should but for some reason the ajax wont accept it. And another strange thing is that when I add for example some random string in front of the queryString then it accepts it. But yes then the query is wrong.

Comment: when I remove one parameter then it works. :D

Comment: index.php?module=tyoaj&page=Fld&action=updateMainTableField&script=Osoitteet

Comment: Hahah now I know what was the actual problem. There were some wrong parameters and the server made a redirect so it showded a different request. Whoah I´m stupid.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think is that your QueryString is not properly encoded.
Try this

```
queryString = queryString.concat(separator, param, "=", encodeURIComponent(config.query[param]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the content inside url after this line `var url = config.url + queryString;`
add `alert(url);` see if the content is what you need it to be

Answer (score 0):

You might use `data` parameter to pass your params:

```
var queryString = "";
var separator = "";

for (param in config.query) {
    queryString = queryString.concat(separator, param, "=", config.query[param]);
    separator = "&";
}

$.ajax({
    url: config.url,
    data: queryString,
    ...
});
```